# How to use EXISTS in DataTable filterExpression?

Tags: c#, .net

I need get exists with filtering `DataTable` in `C#.net` I have tried with

```
string sortExpression="id ASC";
string filterExpression;
DataTable dt;
DataRow[] drA;
filterExpression = "exists (select distinct id from table_b b where a.id=b.id )";
drA = dtAdvancedSearched.Select(filterExpression, sortExpression);
dt = drA .CopyToDataTable();
```

But this will generate an error

Please can any one help me to use exists in .net

Comment: The error is

The expression contains undefined function call exists().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `exists` in in the [RowFilter syntax](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

So i would suggest to use [`Linq-To-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386977.aspx) instead:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> tableBRows = table_b.AsEnumerable();
DataTable dt = dtAdvancedSearched.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => tableBRows.Any(b => b.Field<int>("id") == row.Field<int>("id")))
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<int>("id"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I have tried with your code but there is error on a

The name a does not exists in the current context

Comment: @Wella: Sorry, seems to be a renaming issue ;) So instead of `tableBRows.Any(b => a.Field...` use `Any(b => b`. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is error as "Specified cast is not valid." from your code 3rd line

Comment: @Wella: The only cast is in `DataRow.Field`, so the type of the `id`-column in `dtAdvancedSearched` or/and `table_b` seems not to be `int`. If it's actually string you just have to use (for example): `b.Field<string>("id")`.

Comment: Yes I have used data type according to my data table data type. But That error will generate, There for i used there dr["AH_ID"] == row["AH_ID"]
Now generate this error But accrding to the data sets i need to get results with some records 

The source contains no DataRows.

Comment: What is the actual type of the columns in both tables? Do you still get an error? What means _source contains no DataRows_, what's source?

Comment: there i have used ulong as data type For testing i have used those data table with some equal values 
but still i generate an error<

Also i have problem when it result not exists any data row there will generate error when copy to data table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30397/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-wella)

Answer (score 2):

You could use linq:

```
bool exist = db.Ids.Any (u => u.id == "whateverID");
```

If you want to use it with datatable use Linq-To-Dataset. Add reference to:

> System.Data.DataSetExtensions

and use:

**for string field:**

```
bool exist = tabla.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Field<string>("id") == "whatever");
```

**for int field:**

```
bool exist = tabla.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Field<int>("id") == 5);
```

Comment: i need solution without using linq

Comment: He wants the `EXISTS` syntax, not `WHERE`. So like an `INNER JOIN` to `table_b`.

Answer (score 1):

Check Length of data rows collection.

```
filterExpression = "select distinct  id from table_b b where a.id=b.id";
drA = dtAdvancedSearched.Select(filterExpression, shortExpression);

if(drA.Length != 0)
{
    // do something...
    dt = drA .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Edit

First approach not working so posted another approach

```
DataTable dt = dtAdvancedSearched.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2");
```

Comment: this generate an error 

Syntax error: Missing operand after 'distinct' operator

Comment: `DataTable.Select` does not allow real sql, it's a very limited [syntax](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)to calculate values from the current datatable. So this doesn't work. Don't forget that a `DataTable` is just a in-memory object.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yes you are right, now i updated my answer. thanks